# How can I access a web page protected with username password and show it in webview

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am using a webview control and I want to access a webpage which asks for user name and password. I have the username and password but I dont want to prompt the user for credentials, how can I pass username and password with the url and login and access the webpage???
Example:
I want to access the modem configuration from web view. It asks for username and password before showing the interface.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but you can probably ask your code to fill the login and password textboxes and then programmatically click on the submit button.

Comment: `HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "password");
            
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            string body = await client.GetStringAsync(@"http://192.168.1.1"); // gives exception on this line`

This is how I am trying to access the modem configuration interface 

but getting exception.

Comment: Yeah, did you try to put the login and mdp in the url like:
[http://login:mdp@192.168.1.1](http://login:mdp@192.168.1.1)?
I know the logs aren't visible that way but i can't be sure this way works with the "192.168.1.1" adress.